# Print all variables and their values

Tags: python

This question has been asked quite a bit, and I've tried each solution I come across, but haven't had any success. I'm trying to print out every variable and its value using the following two lines.

```
for name, value in globals():
    print(name, value)
```

This gives an error: `Too many values to unpack`
When I run:

```
for name in globals():
    print(name)
```

I only get the names of the variables. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of what it prints out?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`globals()` returns a `dict` - so, to iterate through a `dict`'s key/value pairs, you call it's `items()` method:

```
dog = 'cat'
>>> for name, value in globals().items():
...     print(name, value)
... 
('__builtins__', <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>)
('__name__', '__main__')
('dog', 'cat')
('__doc__', None)
('__package__', None)
>>>
```

This is explained within the docs for Data Structures, available [here!](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques)

Python 3 version:

```
for name, value in globals().copy().items():
    print(name, value)
```

if we do not copy the output globals functions then there will be RuntimeError.

Also if there are list and dictionaries in the output of some variable then use [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)() instead of copy()

```
for name, value in globals().deepcopy().items():
    print(name, value)
```

Comment: Or you could just use `list(globals().items())` to make that copy, or avoid adding new global names altogether with a generator expression: `print(*(f"{n} {v}" for n, v in globals().items()), sep="\n")`

Comment: This does not appear to work if you have a dict in your global space.
`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'deepcopy'`